# Internet explorer 11 javascript array sort invalid results

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on javascript dealer search functionality:
http://www.example.com/kw_haendlersuche_bug

Try type "74564" in "Adresse" field and press enter. Result will be sorted list of dealers by distance.

On IE11 result will be different than on other browsers.

The key part of dealersearch_de_bug.js (line 166):

```
var c_sort = function(a, b) {
    return a.dist - b.dist;
};
markers.sort(c_sort);
```

But when I sort it twice - http://www.example.com/kw_haendlersuche

dealersearch_de.js line 166:

```
var c_sort = function(a, b) {
    return a.dist - b.dist;
};
markers.sort(c_sort);
markers.sort(c_sort);
```

Result is different and close to the result from other browsers.

What is going on?

Comment: why not use `return a.dist - b.dist;`?

Comment: No difference, I've tried both.

Comment: Have you looked at how they are different? If 2 markers have the same dist, you cannot guarantee the order they will appear, and sorting twice will most likely give a different sort order

Comment: Yes, I know that. Here this is not the case.

Comment: `Array.sort()` works on the given array. no assigment required.

Comment: You're right, but no difference...

Comment: can you check if sort is called in ie11 or not. (typeof is a keyword, not a function. it should be sufficient to replace `if (typeof(foundLocation) !== 'undefined') {` with `if (foundLocation) {`.)

Comment: Yes, sort is called. I have created breakpoint on line 169. Everything looks same from the flow point of view. Just different results of sorting. I have implemented your proposition but no difference.

Comment: It looks like your website overloaded the main Array constructor. It's possible one of the additional functions being added (e.g., _each) is used in IE's sorting. You're also loading dozens of scripts from different places (all.js is being loaded twice, by the way), so without spending an hour poking around I couldn't even locate what library is doing that. In your place, the first thing I'd do is try to turn that off and see if IE behavior changed.

Comment: This is true, but makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the elements in your `markers` array has a `NaN` value for the `dist` property. (It's `markers[482]` in your current test case.) This is throwing off IE's `sort()` function - and in other browsers too.

If you remove any such markers from your array before sorting, then it sorts correctly. You could do this with an `if( ! isNaN(distance) )` test where you create the `var current` and push it to the `markers` array.

I also agree with Curtis's comment about the libraries modifying `Array.prototype` - that can be dangerous because two libraries may step on each other. That isn't the cause of this particular problem though - the same error occurs if you sort the `markers` array in a vanilla test page with no libraries. Here is a simple example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sort Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function log( array, text ) {
            document.write(
                '[ ' + array.join(', ') + ' ] ' + text + '<br>'
            );
        }

        var array = [ 3, 9, NaN, 5, 4 ];
        log( array, 'original' );
        array.sort( function( a, b ) { return a - b; } );
        log( array, 'sorted' );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load this page in IE11 it displays:

```
[ 3, 9, NaN, 5, 4 ] original
[ 3, 4, 9, NaN, 5 ] sorted
```

It also fails to sort correctly in Chrome:

```
[ 3, 9, NaN, 5, 4 ] original
[ 3, 9, NaN, 4, 5 ] sorted
```

and Firefox:

```
[ 3, 9, NaN, 5, 4 ] original
[ 4, 5, NaN, 3, 9 ] sorted
```

I suspect that your page was also not sorting correctly in the other browsers but was just "close enough" - unless for some reason the `NaN` value did not appear in those browsers.

Why does the `NaN` value mess up sorting so badly? Well, sorting depends on being able to compare any two values of an array and get consistent results: less than, greater than, or equal.

But `NaN` doesn't work like an ordinary number. You can compare *any* value with `NaN` and the result is always `false`, no matter what the comparison is - even if you compare with the same `NaN` value:

```
console.log( NaN == NaN );  // false!
```

Similarly if you add or subtract `NaN` in an expression, you always get `NaN` as a result. All of this wreaks havoc with a sort function, whether it uses comparisons or subtraction.

Comment: not only `NaN` makes funny things, as well as objects with absent properties.